# Android Studio. Счетчик в методе onClick

Tags: android-studio, android-on-click, setonclicklistener

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста реализовать счетчик в onClick. Суть в том чтобы на третий клик выполнялось условие, проблема в реализации трех кликов.

[image: onClick]

Comment: Код на SO не принято выкладывать скриншотом. Тем более особого труда его оформить нормально, не требуется.

Comment: это оно что, само в себе при клике слушатель вешает или что за onClick() вначале, к какому виджету он привязан